# How to insert directly into cells of xlsx file in WPF?

Tags: wpf

I have a very generic code to create excel file. I need to insert a collection into cells directly without using gradview

Comment: I advice you to use NPOI( http://npoi.codeplex.com/ )

Comment: And I advise you to read the [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page from the Stack Overflow Help Center and edit your question accordingly before it is closed by the community.